# Vue Cli 3 Build not minifying css

Tags: vue.js, vue-ssr

I have been looking into Vue and have got it working with what I need.

- Typescript
- SSR

My sample project can be found at https://github.com/Alik2015/VueDemo. To run

```
  npm install
  npm run ssr:serve //development
  npm run ssr:build //production build
  npm run ssr:start
```

View source of page and see css has not been minified.

When building this project I observe the following:

1) My css is in the head section of the page and not extracted (read somewhere this is default behaviour but not 100% sure)

2) My comments still  still exists in the css for example /*comment*/

3) My html losing all spacing

I did try  and set css:{extract:true} and various other options in vue.config.js but them just left it blank as none worked.

Appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

I am not a front-end developer so might have missed something simple.